# How to get bulk write metrics in MongoDB Java driver 3.0

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver, mongo-java

I want to get bulk write metrics from Mongo server, like count of insertions, deletions, modifications, but the following methods always return 0.

```
 BulkWriteResult.getInsertedCount()
 BulkWriteResult.getMatchedCount()
 BulkWriteResult.getDeletedCount()
 BulkWriteResult.getModifiedCount()
```

this is my code snippet-

```
 List<ReplaceOneModel<Document>> request = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( new ReplaceOneModel<>(
            new Document("_id", "133499"),
            document,
            new ReplaceOptions().upsert(true))));

 BulkWriteResult writeResult = mongoCollection.bulkWrite(request);
 writeResult.getInsertedCount(),
 writeResult.getMatchedCount(),
 writeResult.getDeletedCount(),
 writeResult.getModifiedCount());
```

All bulk writes are executed successfully, but the counts of insertions, modifications, always return 0.

Comment: That is request a 'replace' operation, so it will only have an effect if there is a document in the collection with an `_id` field whose value is the string "133499".  Is there such a document?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/#db.collection.replaceone--) it only upserts if you explicitly set `upsert` to true.  Have you tried passing options to that [constructor](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/ReplaceOneModel.html)?

Comment: yeah i have edited the code in the question, i have run my code with `upsert` set to true, upserts are working fine, but insertedCount() always returning 0